# Building menus without nested lists impacts on SEO?

Tags: seo, html, navigation, menu

It's common to create a nested menu like this:

```
<ul class="menu-level0">
  <li>
    Shoes
    <ul class="menu-level1">
      <li>
        Converse
        <ul class="menu-level2">
          <li>All stars</li>
          <li>One star</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Puma</li>
      <li>Vans</li>
      <li>Nike</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Hats</li>
  <li>Tshirts</li>
  <li>Pants</li>
</ul>
```

Is it the best we can do for SEO? But, because of a UX improvement, we instead need to create a "flat" menu like this:

```
<ul class="menu-level0">
  <li>Shoes</li>
  <li>Hats</li>
  <li>Tshirts</li>
  <li>Pants</li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-level1" data-parent="Shoes">
  <li>Converse</li>
  <li>Puma</li>
  <li>Vans</li>
  <li>Nike</li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-level2" data-parent="Converse">
  <li>All stars</li>
  <li>One star</li>
</ul>
```

This negatively impact on SEO? If yes, how much?

Comment: What would make you think that menu list structure has any impact on SEO at all?

Answer (score 1):

its lesser your menu, but rather nesting of your urls/folders, which makes impact on SEO. It means: flatter nesting == better for SEO, because of lesser efforts for Googlebot.

About menu: it should be crawlable as static HTML - don't do it with AJAX or similar. But thats pretty all about these things.